# Wortstellung in Nebensätzen

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause

> ... welche die Annahme begründen, dass ihm abweichend von der allgemeinen Lage im Herkunftsstaat politische **Verfolgung droht**.

Hat der Nebensatz in diesem Beispiel die richtige Wortstellung? Muss man nicht mit dem Subjekt (hier **Verfolgung**) den Nebensatz starten?

Comment: Muss man nicht mit "_dem_ Subjekt" (hier Verfolgung)  "_den_ Nebensatz"starten? Den Artikel nicht vergessen! ;-).

Comment: Das ist noch ganz unklar für mich, wie man Artikeln in Deutsch benutzt ;)

Comment: „wie man im Deutschen Artikel benutzt“ ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Das ist ein guter Grund für neue Frage, aber... :-)
Wieso benutzt man den Dativ "DeutschEN" und "Deutsch"?

Comment: Vielleicht hilft http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/das-deutsch-or-das-deutsche.

Comment: @Karl: Ich war so frei, und habe die Artikel eingefügt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dass das Subjekt immer vorne ist, ist einer der gängigen Mythen, den alle voneinander abschreiben.

Die Wortstellung im Nebensatz ist generell weniger flexibel als in Hauptsätzen. In der Sprachwissenschaft werden Sätze nur in der Nebensatzordnung analysiert, da sich dort die "natürliche" Ordnung am deutlichsten zeigt.
Welche die "natürliche" Ordnung ist, hängt vom Satz und vom Kontext ab. Sie ist für jeden Satz anders. Zwei allgemeine Tendenzen sind:

- Das Verb sowie Elemente, die dem Verb inhaltlich sehr nahe stehen, stehen ganz hinten.
- Die Hauptneuigkeit des Satzes, das "Rhema" steht hinten

Das Subjekt steht oft vorne, da keiner der beiden Punkte darauf zutrifft. In deinem Beispiel jedoch schon.
"Verfolgung" ist nicht ein beliebiges Subjekt. Ich kann es nicht durch "ich" oder "du" ersetzen, ohne den Sinn der verbalen Phrase grundlegend zu verändern.

- Verfolgung droht dir.
- Ich drohe dir.

Wenn man will, kann man "Verfolgung droht" als fixe Phrase betrachten.
Dazu kommt, dass "Verfolgung" in diesem Satz die Hauptneuigkeit ist. Das ist es, was wir über den Protagonisten ("ihm") lernen.

> …, dass ihm *(bekannter Protagonist; Thema)* abweichend blah blah Herkunftsstaat *(nähere Beschreibung der Hauptsache)* politische Verfolgung droht *(Rhema – Hauptinformation)*.

Dieses ist die natürlichste Ordnung des Satzes und genau die gleiche wie im folgenden Beispiel:

> …, dass ich meinem Bruder *(Protagonisten … bis zu einem bestimmten Grad bekannt, Thema)* gestern nach der Arbeit *(nähere Bestimmung)* ein Buch gegeben habe *(Rhema – Hauptneuigkeit)*.

Answer (score -1):

Der Satz ist richtig, aber vergiss nicht das Komma hinter "ihm" und "Herkunftsstaat", da diese Phrase ein weiterer Nebensatz ist.

Comment: *abweichend von der allgemeinen Lage im Herkunftsstaat* ist kein Nebensatz, da ihm ein (konjugiertes) Verb fehlt. Je nach Kontext kann man es als Einschub ansehen und darf ein Komma setzen; verpflichtend ist es aber nicht.