# Is the German language "das Deutsche" or "Deutsch"?

Tags: grammatical-case, article

In the dictionary the German language is listed as

> das Deutsche, however one usually hears it referred to simply as "Deutsch"

For instance, I subscribe to a German for foreigners magazine published by die Zeit called "Deutsch Perfekt", I own a Langescheidt "Deutsch als Fremdsprache" dictionary as well as several Deutsch-Englisch dictionaries and I took a "Deutsch-Test für Zuwanderer" test when I took German citizenship. Also, one might be asked "Sprechen Sie Deutsch?" but never "Sprechen Sie das Deutsche?"

Could someone please explain  to me the difference between "das Deutsche" and "Deutsch" in reference to the German language.

Edit: I started to think about this after reading an article titled "Diese Wörter gibt es nur **im Deutschen**".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Das Deutsch" or "das Deutsche"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/das-deutsch-or-das-deutsche)

Comment: @David Vogt. Not really, but it does give some insight. I saw this thread before posting my question.

Comment: Can you explain the difference in the two questions? Do so preferentially in an edit to yours

Comment: I think @tofro's answer in the linked question is the most useful, though you have to scroll a bit to find it. For future reference, link to related questions when you pose your question. It helps to summarize why you think the answers were unhelpful or how your issue is different. It also helps to do all this in the first paragraph; it bad style, since you're burying the lead, but you should allow for people who don't read the whole question.

Answer (score 1):

What you asked for deutsch/Deutsch/das Deutsche concerns all adjectives and names that belong to countries and languages

There is the adjective *»deutsch«* that has two meanings, so does *»englisch«*:

1. belonging to **Germany** or **England** (the country)

   > Die **deutsche** Bundesregierung hat ein Gesetz beschlossen.
   > Essex ist eine **englische** Grafschaft.
2. belonging to **German** or **English** (the language)

   > Die **deutschen** Untertitel sind sehr hilfreich.
   > "Vienna" ist der **englische** Name von Wien.

Both versions can be nominalized:

1. beloning to **Germany/England**

   > - (m) Der Deutsche und der Engländer haben sich ein Taxi geteilt.
   > - (f) Eine Deutsche und eine Engländerin sitzen am selben Tisch.
   > - (n) Das Deutsche ist eine Lebensart, die mit Gründlichkeit aber auch mit Bier in Verbindung gebracht wird, so wie man sich das Englische kaum ohne Tee und die Liebe zur Queen vorstellen kann.
2. belonging to **German/English**

   > - (only n) *April* ist ein Wort, das im Deutschen dasselbe bedeutet wie im Englischen.

---

Besides that there is also the neuter noun *»das Deutsch«* (*»das Englisch«*) which is not a nominalized adjective but a proper noun and usually is used without an article:

> Deutsch ist mit Englisch verwandt.

But you can also use it with articles in some cases:

> Das Deutsch, das Martin Luther vor 500 Jahren sprach, ist heute kaum noch verständlich.
> Das Englisch der Queen klingt sehr nobel.

The difference is already described in [another answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/8277/1487): You use *»das Deutsch«* with article, if you mean a special variety of the German language, but you use *»Deutsch«* without article if you mean the German language in general.

Another difference is, that the nominalized adjective can not be used in situation where other nominalized adjectives would be used in strong declension:

- weak declension

  > Wenn zwei **das Gleiche** tun, ist es noch lange nicht dasselbe.
  > **Das Deutsche** ist eine Sprache, die vorwiegend in Europa gesprochen wird.
  > **Das Englische** ist eine Weltsprache.
- strong declension

  > Er will **Gleiches** mit Gleichem vergelten.
  > wrong: Er spricht kein **Deutsches.** Er spricht kein **Englisches.**
  > correct: Er spricht kein **Deutsch.** Er spricht kein **Englisch.**

---

- Name of the teaching subject: proper noun without article

  > Heute steht um 8:00 Uhr Deutsch auf dem Stundenplan, anschließend Englisch.
- General name of the language: proper noun without article

  > In Österreich und Deutschland spricht man Deutsch, in den USA und in England spricht man Englisch.
  > Sprechen Sie Deutsch? Sprechen Sie Englisch?
- Specific version of a language: proper noun with article

  > Sprechen Sie das Deutsch das Goethe gesprochen hat? Sprechen Sie das Englisch der Queen?
- Not part of the subject, in a grammatical environment where nominalized adjectives will be declined weakly (especially inside prepositional objects): nominalized adjective with article

  > Das Buch wurde ins (= in das) Deutsche (ins Englische) übersetzt.
  > Diese Wörter gibt es nur im (= in dem) Deutschen (im Englischen).

Comment: Ich kann den folgenden Satzt nicht ganz verstehen: "Another difference is, that the nominalized adjective can not be used in situation where other nominalized adjectives would be used in strong declension..." Meinen Sie, das ist der Unterschied zwischen substantivierten Sprachnamen und anderen substantivierten Adjektiven?

Comment: @ALÖ: Es geht darum, dass das ordentliche Substantiv *»das Deutsch«* und das substantivierte Adjektiv *»das Deutsche«* nicht beliebig austauschbar sind. Wenn das substantivierte Adjektiv schwach gebeugt werden muss, können beide Formen verwendet werden: *»Das Deutsche kling schön. Deutsch klingt schön.«* Wenn aber eine Konstruktion gewählt wird, in der das substantivierte Adjektiv, das eine Sprache benennt, stark gebeugt werden müsste, kann man es nicht verwenden. Darin unterscheidet es sich vom ordentl. Substantiv: Falsch: *»Er spricht kein Deutsches.«* Richtig: *»Er spricht kein Deutsch.«*

Comment: Alles klar, danke